# Analyzing TCB Index Status for DB2

Tags: database, db2, indexing, database-indexes

The Following is the TCB index that I could get using a command for my DB2 database. I don't know how to analyze it. Which columns are important? what do they mean? I know this is kind of a newbie question but plz help me out.

TCB Index Stats:

```
Address            TableName    IID   EmpPgDel   RootSplits BndrySplts PseuEmptPg Scans      KeyUpdates InclUpdats NonBndSpts PgAllocs   Merges     PseuDels   DelClean   IntNodSpl  
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         21    2128       0          5          2143       191        1738530    0          7916       6016       0          1805985    1743606    26         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         20    357        0          2332       357        1242710    1738530    0          2584       4054       0          1812241    1652843    15         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         19    662        1          4293       662        16464      1907107    0          4907       7537       0          2004994    1556457    46         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         18    184        0          1689       184        2788625    1738530    0          1044       2235       0          1811998    1709486    6          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         17    4705       1          0          4990       1210257    2017860    0          14890      11525      0          2119054    2067832    71         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         16    5754       0          422        5923       116        1878324    0          15534      12105      0          1979092    1815142    95         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         15    309        0          0          309        59269      1738530    0          5403       4419       0          1809592    1667684    13         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         14    1          0          0          1          1964       38286      0          640        556        0          139952     121125     0          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         13    0          1          0          0          1025       85         0          599        540        0          16995      15319      1          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         12    55         0          549        55         3333550    85         0          404        787        0          103223     102424     0          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         11    0          1          0          0          0          85         0          667        583        0          92226      87623      1          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         10    0          0          0          0          2311       85         0          664        582        0          102572     88222      0          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         9     2119       0          0          2530       92242      1738530    0          7482       5870       0          1810986    1764093    19         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         8     42         0          0          46         5140       1401046    0          679        538        0          1468321    1457986    0          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         7     770        0          514        959        1040       1738530    0          3460       3294       0          1809636    1758940    10         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         6     71         0          0          71         208155     105241     0          1716       1488       0          205678     183839     3          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         5     881        0          5          1094       459        1738530    0          4426       3622       0          1809593    1766681    11         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         4     176        0          1837       172        2104       3016234    0          1068       2111       0          3119296    1655094    2          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         3     2056       0          0          2539       945246     1738530    0          7459       5829       0          1810990    1778688    20         
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         2     14         0          0          14         1956       827370     0          767        606        0          914780     715791     0          
0x07000000EA695040 TAB1         1     42         0          1120       42         14577342   0          0          640        1436       0          103138     100282     2          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         22    53         0          804        52         101027     0          0          0          770        0          36098      34766      1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         21    0          0          310        0          406873     175642     0          565        849        0          211482     147209     1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         20    176        0          0          172        7117       3463       0          4196       4033       0          38044      38154      36         
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         19    244        0          4418       238        2271510    0          2286113    0          4222       0          36098      36680      4          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         18    431        0          4543       1152       1614       2286113    0          3338       7482       0          2321909    2262963    98         
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         17    46         0          697        46         121        0          0          0          669        0          36098      34754      1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         16    23         0          394        23         6600       0          0          0          378        0          36098      30821      0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         15    122        0          0          119        1497610    0          0          1729       1659       0          36098      35976      7          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         14    0          0          293        0          103031     86453      0          109        388        0          122249     78577      0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         13    156        0          0          371        26611      2286113    0          3234       3103       0          2321909    2276441    13         
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         12    43         0          680        43         11827      0          0          0          653        0          36098      33917      1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         11    1          0          598        1          63852      86453      0          425        986        0          122289     85714      2          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         10    62         0          918        61         18190      0          0          0          881        0          36098      36052      1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         9     32         0          518        32         209418     36098      0          0          496        0          72196      72112      0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         8     13         0          0          13         6383       3463       0          222        219        0          37922      33539      1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         7     43         0          670        43         23306      0          0          0          642        0          36098      34458      1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         6     31         0          518        31         181547     0          0          0          495        0          36098      36044      0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         5     32         0          519        32         209546     36098      0          0          498        0          72196      72143      0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         4     11         0          1384       9          7003       2286113    0          23         1332       0          2321909    1000172    1          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         3     0          0          0          0          6328       0          0          211        208        0          18539      13686      0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         2     0          0          136        0          59348      175642     0          139        266        0          211426     157453     0          
0x07000000E97B80C0 TAB2         1     31         0          483        31         8304809    0          0          0          462        0          36098      36008      0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you have also posted on dba.stackexchange.com. I posted [an answer there](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/16882/analyzing-tcb-index-status-for-db2) to your question.